# В html страницах при нажатии или наведении на ссылку вида http://xxx.yy вырезается символ ":"

Tags: html, http, https

В html страницах при нажатии или наведении на ссылку вида http://xxx.yy вырезается символ ":".

Я обнаружил это при тестировании своего сайта на предмет восстановления забытого пароля.
Ссылка на html странице упрощенно записана так: http://xxx.yy.
На результирующей странице та часть, которая заключена внутри тега  выглядит как положено, т.е. http://xxx.yy, но если навести на неё указатель мыши, то в строке подсказки, в нижней части браузера, она выглядит уже так: http//xxx.yy. И при нажатии в адресную строку браузера попадает именно эта, измененная ссылка.
Причем все ссылки, начинающиеся как https://, отображаются и отрабатывают как положено.
Первоначально, я предположил, что эта проблема связана с Firefox-ом, но в Microsoft Edge результат тот же. Конечно, я временно решил проблему, вообще избавившись от части http://.
Пока работает так.
У меня вопрос: в чем дело?
Предполагаю, что это очередной шаг к окончательному запрету использования сайтов без поддержки шифрования. Так ли это?

Ниже представлен скриншот с примером.
[image: Это скриншот с примером с https://e.mail.ru]

Comment: Предполагаю что это какой-то кривой скрипт на странице

Comment: Вообще-то, все это безобразие в почтовом клиенте на Yandex

Comment: Стало ещё более непонятно. Что такое почтовый клиент на яндекс?

Comment: На https://e.mail.ru - то же самое, пример смотрите в описании выше.

Comment: На mail.yandex.ru - это то место, которое называют почтовым сервисом Яндекса.

Comment: Покажите исходный код тела письма (можно без заголовков) для более конкретных разбирательств

Comment: Лучше показать скрипт, который формирует письмо.

Comment: У вас письмо кривое и Яндекс и мэйл тут ни при чём. Чините письмо

Answer (score 0):

Mea culpa - моя вина! 
Прошу извинить за беспокойство. 
Проблема в том, что изначально было неизвестно, какой домен будет использоваться в окончательном варианте, тем более, что в режиме разработки использовался локальный сервер. Поскольку приложение клиент-серверное (react/flask), чтобы лишний раз не трогать серверную часть, которая была уже вчерне разработана, на клиентской стороне название домена было включено в конфигурационный файл. На тот момент было решено использовать домен без протокола, т.е. 127.0.0.1:8080, а на серверной стороне недостающая часть добавлялась перед отсылкой письма. Приложение было пару раз переписано с нуля, в какой-то момент определились с доменом, и в окончательном варианте решили использовать в конфигурационном файле полностью протокол + домен, а про серверную часть благополучно забыли. Отсюда растут ноги у проблемы. 
Это называется "дурная голова ногам покоя не дает". Еще раз прошу всех извинить меня за беспокойство.  
Всем спасибо за участие... и за урок!